# API REST PHP - Funcionamiento

Tags: php, rest

Tengo una pregunta de cómo funcionan las api rest, no consigo encontrar cómo enviar una petición.

Estoy probando con la api de shopify y tengo el siguiente código:

```
$baseUrl = 'https://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx.myshopify.com/admin'; //Api URL removed for security reasons.

$ordercreate = array ('line_items','variant_id' => '1480829665339',
  'quantity' => '1');

$ch = curl_init($baseUrl.'/orders.json'); //set the url
$data_string = json_encode(array('order' => $ordercreate)); //encode the product as json
echo $data_string;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  //specify this as a POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); //set the POST string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //specify return value as string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
); //specify that this is a JSON call
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch); //get server output if you wish to error handle / debug
echo $server_output;
curl_close ($ch); //close the connection
```

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para enviar esto

```
{
  "order": {
    "email": "foo@example.com",
    "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 447654529,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

En el archivo php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a modificar la línea:

```
$ordercreate = array ('line_items','variant_id' => '1480829665339',
  'quantity' => '1');
```

Y poner los datos que necesitas:

```
$ordercreate = array("email" => "foo@example.com", 
    "fulfillment_status" => "fulfilled",
    "line_items" => array(array(
        "variant_id" => 447654529,
        "quantity" => 1)
    )
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!